# Check of If an account exists

Tags: php, mysql

MY CODE

```
<?php
session_start();
require './SIGNUP/connects1010101.php';
require './LOGIN/connects1010101.php';
$srausername = $_SESSION['SRAUSERNAME'];
$srapassword = $_SESSION["SRAPASSWORD"];
if ($srausername && $srapassword) {
    $data0 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `INFO` WHERE `USERNAME` = '$srausername' AND `PASSWORD` = '$srapassword'");
    $data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($data0);
}
?>
```

I am beginner in PHP. My question is that I am making account register in mysql but how can I check if an account exists or not?

Comment: If account exists and your query executes without errors - `$data1` is not empty.

Comment: To see if it exists, all you need to know is how many rows are returned. Change the ```SELECT *``` to ```SELECT count(*) as `num_found` ``` and check to see if num_found is greater than zero in the results.

Comment: And how to check for errors, as I told, I am Beginner, u_mulder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code like this,

```
<?php
session_start();
require './SIGNUP/connects1010101.php';
require './LOGIN/connects1010101.php';
$srausername = $_SESSION['SRAUSERNAME'];
$srapassword = $_SESSION["SRAPASSWORD"];
if ($srausername && $srapassword) {
    $data0 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `INFO` WHERE `USERNAME` = '$srausername' AND `PASSWORD` = '$srapassword'");
    //$data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($data0);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data0) > 0) {
        // Account already exists
    }else {
        // No account exists and you can save the details here
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    require './SIGNUP/connects1010101.php';
    require './LOGIN/connects1010101.php';
    $srausername = $_SESSION['SRAUSERNAME'];
    $srapassword = $_SESSION["SRAPASSWORD"];



    if ($srausername != '' && $srapassword != '') {
        $data0 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `INFO` WHERE `USERNAME` = '$srausername' AND `PASSWORD` = '$srapassword'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($data0) > 0){
            // new entry
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `INFO` (`USERNAME`,  `PASSWORD`) VALUES ('$srausername', '$srapassword') ");
            if($sql == true){
                echo 'Account has been registered';
                exit();
            }
        }else{
            // account exists
            echo 'Can not register. Account already exists';
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Fields should not be empty!';
        exit();
    }
?>
```